# Discord bot in repl.it

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, replit

I was trying to make a discord bot in python, I found [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/) instruction on freecodecamp. I just copied their code, like in the video, but every time I run it there is this error message:

[image: Error message]

Where is the problem? Please be indulgent I am a novice in programming

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code (no links), approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's happening because you probably forgot to paste your Discord BOT Token into **[secrets](https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/08-storing-secrets-and-history)** (repl.it substitute for `.env` file).

1. Go to your repl on [repl.it](https://replit.com).
2. Go to **secrets** (padlock icon on your left).
3. Use **TOKEN** as your `key` and paste your token inside `value`.
4. Click **save** and it should work!

*Remember to `import os`!*

### Screenshots

***Where are secrets?***

[image: secrets location screenshot]

***Example secret with Discord BOT token:***

[image: Example secret]

Answer (score -2):

make an env and then put TOKEN then enter the bots token